# PyQT5 not displaying open and save dialog

Tags: python, pyqt5

I made a gui with a browse button which prompts the user to select excel files. These file names are then passed to function along with self. The excel files are basically combined into one dataframe. I now want to open an existing excel file, concat the new df onto that one and then save it as a new file.

The issue is the code in the fuction will get to the point where it asks me to Open File but then it will stop and never prompt me for a save name. It throws no errors, it just stops. If I take out the getOpenFileNames prompt it will prompt me to save. It seems to only allow me to do one or the other not both.

```
def function(self,filenames):
  ....
  ....

  file_to_update=QFileDialog().getOpenFileNames(self, "Open File","","Excel (*.xlsx)")
  df_to_update=pd.read_excel(file_to_update,header=0)

  new=pd.concat([df_to_update,mass_calc], axis=0)

  save=QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"Save File","","Excel (*.xlsx)")
  save_name=str(save[0])

  if save_name=="":
    error_dialog = QErrorMessage(self)
    error_dialog.showMessage('No filename entered')
    return
    
    
  new.to_excel(save_name,index=False)
```

Comment: `getOpenFileNames()` (note the trailing *s*) returns a *list* of strings, which could even be empty if the dialog is cancelled. Since `read_excel` seems to only open a single file and you're probably going to need that single file feature too, I suggest you to use `getOpenFileName()` (no trailing *s*) instead, but remember that in PyQt it returns a *tuple*, with the first value being the (possibly empty) path string, and the second the selected file filter.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you! I changed it to getOpenFileName and I extracted the string from the tuple and it worked perfectly